# Node: Cannot use import statement outside a module in Jest

Tags: node.js, axios, jestjs

Until today I have made a lot of testing with jest and I have never received this error. I haven't update my Jest version and the code is the same than other days.

The error received is:

```
josecarlos@R2D2 ~/Workspace/BlueCode/Youmalou/Backend [add/Memcached-2*]$ npx jest ./unittest/memcached.test.js

Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

**By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.**

Details:

/home/josecarlos/Workspace/BlueCode/Youmalou/Backend/node_modules/axios/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import config from "../config";
> 2 | import axios from "axios";
    | ^
  3 | import {Result} from "./result";
  4 | import {PGMappingDDBB} from "../database/postgresql/pg_mapping";
  5 | import {PGBackendDDBB} from "../database/postgresql/pg_backend";

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (com/functions.js:2:1)
```

The axios module is correctly imported and this module is in node_modules and how it is said in the message received **By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.**

My .babelrc is:

```
{
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
   "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
   ]  
}
```

If I add "type": "module" to my package.json it doesn't work.

When I try to run the test I do it with this command: *npx jest ./unittest/memcached.test.js* and how I said this was working without any problem until yesterday but today is not working.

So, how can I fix this error?

### Edit I

I have installed "babel-jest": "^29.7.0" and create the file jest.config.js with this code:

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"]
};
```

And it doesn't work. I receive the same error!

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my issue. I have updated my Jest version to the latest. Now, I have installed 29.7.0 version of Jest.